# Is it possible to not show unmodified locked files in commit dialog

Tags: locking, tortoisesvn

I work on projects where we use locking (many files are non-text files configured with needs-lock). Typically I will be the only one working on a particular project for a long time, hence I typically keep all the locks for long periods (locking/unlocking takes time). When committing, the dialog also shows all the unmodified files because they are locked. This is especially annoying when doing repair move (need to scroll a lot). Is there a setting to not show unmodified files even though they are locked?

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the list of files being committed by the Status column (click the column header), the unmodified files will be pushed to the bottom of the list.

But let's address this:

> Typically I will be the only one working on a particular project for a long time, hence I typically keep all the locks for long periods

Holding locks on files you aren't actively working on will cause problems for people. It prevents directories from being moved/renamed. A repository backup/restore will invalidate all of your locks. If you go on vacation or are otherwise not working for an extended period of time and someone needs to modify one of these files, they'll have to break your lock and any work you might have will be lost (as it's not mergeable). **Always** assume that you're working with a team who needs these files - locks should be held only as long as is necessary.

Comment: I do sort by the status column, but that does not help me much when doing repair move. If I rename something I get one file as missing (old name) and one which is unversioned (new name). When sorting modified and missing are grouped together, but the issue is that all the unmodified/normal files go between them and the unversioned files. One might think that it would be possible to sort, select one, sort again and select the other, but the selection is lost after sorting.

Comment: Thanks for the concern regarding the locking. We are a small team of 5 developers. Typically I will be the only on touching my code, only on rare occasion will someone else need to and then they can steal the lock. We are encouraged to commit often so there should be no uncommited work that gets lost in such circumstances. And although I keep the locks for long periods I know to release all the locks before I go on vacation.